# What are the valid NETWORK values for docker node images?

Tags: cardano-node, docker

I can find no documentation, nor even the original docker image file, for the cardano node docker images. We are trying to direct our node to connect to pre-production. Presumably there is a value for the `NETWORK` environment variable which corresponds to that.

Does anyone know where to fine an enumeration of all valid values for the `NETWORK` var?

For reference, I'm referring to this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/cardano-node

Answer (score 2):

In my experience IOG's bash scripts, used for running `cardano-node`, are poorly documented and have poor error handling. I suggest running `cardano-node` directly with the relevant config files:

```
/usr/local/bin/cardano-node run --config $CARDANO_CONFIG --topology $CARDANO_TOPOLOGY --database-path $CARDANO_DATABASE_PATH --socket-path $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH --host-addr 0.0.0.0 --port 3001
```

The relevant config files can be found here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html

Of course you would have to change the entrypoint of the docker image. For that I suggest creating a new Dockerfile that wraps `inputoutput/cardano-node:latest`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM inputoutput/cardano-node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /data/preprod
RUN mkdir -p /ipc
 
COPY ./config.json /data/preprod/config.json
COPY ./topology.json /data/preprod/topology.json
COPY ./byron-genesis.json /data/preprod/byron-genesis.json
COPY ./shelley-genesis.json /data/preprod/shelley-genesis.json
COPY ./alonzo-genesis.json /data/preprod/alonzo-genesis.json

COPY ./entrypoint /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint"]
```

The `entrypoint` script should contain the first command I mentioned:

```
#!/bin/bash

export CARDANO_CONFIG=/data/preprod/config.json
export CARDANO_TOPOLOGY=/data/preprod/topology.json
export CARDANO_DATABASE_PATH=/data/preprod/db
export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket

exec /usr/local/bin/cardano-node run --config $CARDANO_CONFIG --topology $CARDANO_TOPOLOGY --database-path $CARDANO_DATABASE_PATH --socket-path $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH --host-addr 0.0.0.0 --port 3001
```

Finally build your image and run it:

```
docker build -t cardano-preprodnet .
docker run -d -v cardano-node-data:/data cardano-preprodnet
```

A github repo that does precisely what I described above can be found here: https://github.com/Hyperion-BT/cardano-node-wrappers (disclaimer: I am the creator)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify and having using docker image `cardano-node:1.35.3-configs` you can use environment variable `NETWORK=prepord`

`docker run -e NETWORK=preprod inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3-configs`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen invocations of this this `-new` docker image with environment variable `NETWORK=preprod` set in the #spo-public-testnet channel on IOGs discord. However I do not have any more documentation and would like to know more about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://forum.cardano.org/t/how-i-run-cardano-node-in-docker/108328

That should give you idea how to run official IOHK docker images