# Connect docker cardano-node 1.35.3 to pre-production testnet

Tags: cardano-node, docker

The dockerized version of `cardano-node` version `1.35.3` connects to the mainnet by default. We wish to connect the node to the new pre-production or preview testnets. It isn't made clear in any documentation how to accomplish this.

For reference, I'm referring to this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/inputoutput/cardano-node

This is related to [What are the valid NETWORK values for docker node images?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8937/what-are-the-valid-network-values-for-docker-node-images)

Answer (score 1):

A solution, involving setting up a new docker image, can be found here: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/8940/7460

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it:

Get the config files from here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments/preprod/

Place the config files in `$PWD/config/docker_configs/preprod` where `$PWD` is the dir containing your compose.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  cardano-node-testnet:
    image: inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3
    container_name: cardano_node_testnet
    volumes:
      - node-testnet-db:/data/db
      - node-ipc:/ipc
      - $PWD/config/docker_configs/preprod:/config
    command:
      - run
      - --config /config/config.json
      - --topology /config/topology.json
      - --database-path /data/db
      - --socket-path /ipc/node.socket
    restart: on-failure
    healthcheck:
      # Ping the EKG port to see if it responds.
      # Assuming if EKG isn't up then the rest of cardano-node isn't either.
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f 127.0.0.1:12788 || exit 1" ]
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        compress: "true"
        max-file: "10"
        max-size: "50m"
```

Thanks to adamuso on the iohk discord for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my post in cardano forum here:

https://forum.cardano.org/t/relay-node-in-docker/102416/2?u=os11k

Basically you need to run it in docker compose, config files should be under `./node-config` on host server. Keep in mind in my example I use `testnet-config.json` & `testnet-topology.json` as file names, you can change them in Dockerfile.

And you need to have Dockerfile in same dir where is docker-compose.yml

```
FROM inputoutput/cardano-node:1.35.3
ENV CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/cardano-node", "run", "+RTS", "-N", "-A16m", "-qg", "-qb", "-RTS", "--topology", "/config/testnet-topology.json", "--database-path", "/data/db", "--socket-path", "/ipc/node.socket", "--host-addr", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "6001", "--config", "/config/testnet-config.json" ]
```

That should make it.